# Terminology: Keep screen at full brightness—and opposite

Tags: wording

Background: By default, Android will dim the screen after some time, then after another few minutes switch it off completely.

I’m working on an Android app which allows the user to disable and restore this behavior. That is, one action will make the screen stay at full brightness until the device runs out of power, the other one will revert to the default behavior (bright→dimmed→off). This setting will take effect regardless of which application happens to be in the foreground. Internally, this is done by acquiring a `SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK`.

What would be good terms to describe these two actions? I came up with those:

To keep the screen at full brightness:

- Force screen to stay on at full brightness
- Keep screen on at full brightness
- Prevent screen from dimming or turning off

To revert to default behavior:

- Allow screen to dim or turn off *(which may be incorrect, as other apps may still keep the screen on)*

However, I’m still not happy with those. What would be a good wording for those two actions, clearly understandable and as short as possible?

---

Edit: There seems to be some misunderstanding regarding my question and how Android controls screen brightness, hence I’ll explain that in more detail:

- The user can set the screen brightness to either a fixed value, or have the phone choose screen brightness based on ambient light, or a combination of both. This sets the brightness an app will have while the user is interacting with it. I’m referring to this as full brightness, even though it is not necessarily the maximum brightness the display is capable of producing.
- Unless a certain type of wakelock or flag for the foreground activity are in place, Android will dim the screen after a minute or two.
- After some more time, Android will turn off the screen—again, unless one of the above are in place and only if the “Keep screen on while charging” setting is not checked.

What I’m trying to implement is a feature to inhibit the above behavior and force the screen to maintain full (i.e. user selected) brightness, without dimming after some time and without turning off. This will be event-driven, i.e. the user can choose to enable and disable this feature when certain events occur, therefore I need some descriptive text for both actions.

Comment: The "full brightness" isn't necessarily "full", it is whatever value it was set, right?

Comment: @Alvaro By “full” I’m referring to the brightness at which the screen is while the user is interacting with the device. This is not necessarily maximum brightness, but also not the brightness to which the screen will dim after a certain time without user input.

Comment: That is what I thought, just wanted to confirm :)

Comment: I thought the dimming served two particular purposes: a) react to ambient light to reduce eyestrain for the user and b) warn that the screen is about to lock after inactivity. I'm not sure disabling either of these is a good idea. There may be a third when in battery saving mode but that can be disabled. The ambient brightness can be adjusted and the lock warning doesn't occur is you disable the auto-lock feature (never sleep). Is there something else you are trying to achieve by forcing the screen to full brightness?

Comment: From a UI perspective, would this not just be a switch/checkbox? In which case, you'd only need one label (something like "Prevent screen from dimming or turning off") and not the opposite.

Comment: @MattObee it’s going to be an event-driven set of rules, with quite a few configuration options for the user. Something like “if A happens, prevent screen from dimming”, “if B happens, allow screen to dim or switch off”, “if C happens, launch AcmeApp” and the like. Hence, both actions need a description of their own.

Comment: @AndrewMartin b) is likely, I suppose it’s also a power-saving feature. I have doubts about a), Android has generic settings for that (both the default brightness and for adapting to ambient light). See also my previous coments. The main issue is that the dimmed screen is very hard to read in bright sunlight, even with brightness set to maximum, which is why I want to give users a way to inhibit this dimming.

Comment: @user149408 the problem there is that you will be inhibiting a warning device. In those instances, Android dims the screen to alert the user to the fact that the screen is about to lock. If you prevent the screen from locking then it will not dim.

Comment: @AndrewMartin Android has a setting in developer options to keep the screen on while charging. With this setting enabled, the screen will not lock when the charger is plugged in, but it will still dim. Apps can in fact control the behavior: they can either request the screen to stay on at full brightness, or they can allow it to dim while still keeping it on. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#newWakeLock(int,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

Max-Bright  |or|  Max Brightness

vs

Auto-dim

If you decide to use a toggle, I recommend you call the toggle "Auto-dim" in which you turn it on and off.  It will be intuitive to the user that when you turn off auto-dim, the screen provides max brightness.

Another alternative is to use icons. The "Max Bright" icon could be a sun.  The "Auto-dim" icon could be a sunset.

Using an icon plus the text description might be the best approach from a UX perspective.